# Как вытащить вектор из private и присвоить ему размер

Tags: c++, vector

Есть класс

````
```class 
Person
{ 
private: 
vector<Account*> acc;
..
}
```
````

при вызове в main - надо, чтобы acc принял значение размера.Пробую в public записать

````
```
void Person::setAccount( int x)
{
  acc=acc(x);

}

std::vector<Account*> Person::getAccount()
{
   return acc;
}
```
````

Естественно выдает ошибку..

Comment: Какую ошибку? И приведите [mre] этой ошибки. Также в коде не должно быть ```

Comment: `acc` - это вектор указателей, какое значение он должен по вашему принять? Если вы хотите задать размер вектора, то есть методы `resize` и `reserve`, в зависимости от того, что вы хотите.

Comment: Ещё есть конструктор с одним параметром для этого (но он должен быть вызван без списковой инициализации, иначе будет `initializer_list`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Непонятно, что вы хотите. Изменить размер вектора? (*"Чтобы acc принял значение размера"*)?

Тогда просто

```
void Person::resize(size_t x)
{
    acc.resize(x);
}
```

Что до вашего

```
std::vector<Account*> Person::getAccount()
{
   return acc;
}
```

И какую ошибку выдает здесь?..

Comment: setAccount - выдает ошибку. getAccount - просто возвращает вектор с 0 размером. Я же не могу напрямую обратиться к acc в функции. А надо, когда class Person вызывается - вызвался class Account определенного размера.

Comment: @Cat потому что у вектора нет `operator()`

Comment: Ну правильно, но ошибки-то нет - вы возвращаете копию вектора. Что должен делать ваш `setAccount`, поясните - что вы хотели добиться? `x` - это размер, новый элемент (не получится - элементы у вас - указатели...) или что?

Comment: @Harry setAccount должен принимать число n и делать  вектор Account  размера n . Извините за не четкое объяснение

Comment: Кто нибудь переведите на понятный язык: "*...когда class Person вызывается - вызвался class Account определенного размера*", я ничего не понял

Comment: Тогда так, как я написал. Вектор будет нужного размера, заполненный нулевыми указателями. А если вы хотите - то можно и в конструктор засунуть: `Person::Person(size_t x):acc(x) { ... }`.

Answer (score 0):

В зависимости от того, что вам нужно _ добавить такой конструктор:

```
explicit Person(size_t n = 0) noexcept
               : acc(vector<Account*>(n)) {}
```

(тогда объект Person(5) , будет иметь вектор размера 5).

Или оператор:

```
Person& operator =(const vector<Account*>&);
```

и много других вариантов...